# Annoying popping sound when using external usb mixer

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have Ubuntu 20.04, and I started getting a pooping noise whenever I play any sound through my Xenyx 302 USB mixer.

I already changed the default to 48000 almost everything I have tried has not worked

Linux louie-HP-Laptop-17-by2xxx 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux